# To Fix Empty Space between index of array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Wanna save space of between columns that how many are..
Iv wrote this but there is a bug here.. how can i get its answer???
for example:
input is {3, 0, 2, 0, 4} and output should be just a number that here for this input is 7.

```
        int[] input = {3, 0, 2, 0, 4};
    
        int inputLength = input.length;
        System.out.println("inputLength: " + inputLength);
        int vol = 0,pos = 0;

        if (inputLength >= 3) {
            while (pos <= inputLength - 1) {
                if (input[pos + 1] <= input[pos]) {
                    pos++;
                 
                } else if (input[pos + 1] < input[pos]) {
                    System.out.println("pos=" + pos);
                    int gapStartPos = pos;
                    int gapStartHeight = input[pos];
                       
                    int gapEndPos = pos;
                    int gapEndHeight = input[pos];
                
                    int e = pos;
                    for (int i = e + 1; i < inputLength; i++) {
                        if ((input[i] != 0) && (input[i] >= (gapStartHeight - 1))) {
                            gapEndPos = i;
                            gapEndHeight = input[i];
                      
                            break;
                        } else {

                            gapEndPos++;
                           
                        }

                    }
                       
                    for (int i = gapStartPos + 1; i < gapEndPos; i++) {
                        vol += (Math.floor((gapStartHeight + gapEndHeight) / 2) - input[i]);
                        System.out.println("vol=" + vol);
                    }
                                         
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture-Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZZ2n.png)

[Picture-Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gN6p.png)

Comment: I ran this code and did not run into any errors (though the loop never ends).

Comment: plz see that 2 image under code..

Comment: output is wrong..